# Repeat Stream allMatch() until true

Tags: java, java-8

```
int testValue;
boolean success = false;

while(success == false) {
 testValue = generateRandomInt();   
 success = mySystem.getHosts().parallelStream().allMatch(predicate(testValue));
}

return testValue;
```

I am playing around with java8 streams. What do you suggest to make the code above more elegant/readable?

Comment: It's a bad habit to test against boolean literals (true/false). It's very easy to accidentally write `while(success = false)` instead of `while(success == false)`. `while(!success)` is safer and more concise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an infinite `IntStream` instead of the `while` loop, and return the first `int` of the stream that matches your condition:

```
return IntStream.generate (() -> generateRandomInt())
                .filter (i -> mySystem.getHosts().parallelStream().allMatch(predicate(i)))
                .findFirst()
                .getAsInt();
```

Comment: @Moonlit Yeah, I made some errors initially (I still get the return types of some of the Stream methods mixed up) :)

Comment: The last edit was pointless, using `findFirst` instead of `findAny` is just misleading; the stream returned by `IntStream.generate` is already unordered by definition.

Answer (score 8):

You could do it with `jdk-9`s `takeWhile`(when it's available):

```
  Stream.generate(() -> generateRandomInt())
        .takeWhile(x -> mySystem.getHosts().parallelStream().allMatch(predicate(x)))
        .findAny()
        .get();
```

Comment: Obviously this is subjective, but I strongly disagree with your choice of formatting. There's no visual indication that `.allMatch()` is called on the inner stream, unless you closely examine the parentheses. I would either move it to the previous line or indent it.